# How to make assertions for subscripted variables?

Tags: assumptions, subscript

I'm trying to write a formula using [subscripted](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) variables like `x₁, x₂, x₃, ...`, so that I can later retrieve their values programmatically. However, I'm struggling with making [assumptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) for such symbols.

```
In[1] := Conjugate[x₁ + I x₂]
Out[1] := Conjugate[x₁]  − I Conjugate[x₂]

In[2] := Refine[Conjugate[x₁ + I x₂], {(x₁|x₂) ∈ ℝ}]
Out[2] := Conjugate[x₁]  − I Conjugate[x₂]
```

How can I tell Mathematica, that all `xᵢ` are reals?

Comment: Better to use `x[1]`, etc.  `Subscript` is a formatting function, and a subscripted variables sometimes do not act like real variables.

Comment: Running the same code, but with `x[i]` instead of every `xᵢ`, produces the exact same result. The assumption doesn't work for `x[1] | x[2]` either.

Comment: Look at the docs for `ComplexExpand` then `Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]; Conjugate[x[1] + I*x[2]] // ComplexExpand`

Comment: @m93a It worked for me fine, as soon as I replaced R by Reals: `Refine[Conjugate[x₁ + I x₂], {(x₁ | x₂) \[Element] Reals}]` returns `x₁ - I x₂`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Could you please specify, when the subscripted variables do not act as standard ones? So far, I spotted two such situations: 1. During simplification. This is because the tree structure of `x1` is different from `Subscript[x,1]`, and 2. The problems to clear the subscripted variables always arise.  Do you know something else?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch To be frank, I have seen such concerns so often on this site that I assume they must be so, but I have no first-hand experience.  I never use `Subscript`, etc.  Sorry.